# How to fix ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'"?

Tags: ios, xcode

I made an application and when I try to submit I got an error. 
The error is `ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'"`.

I also did this in my `Info.plist`:
[image]

Here are my `xcassets`
[image]

I don't know why it's not working. And if I remove icons from `Supporting Files` and from `Info.plist`, and try to submit it is showing these two errors:

`ERROR ITMS-90032: "Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'"`

`ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."`

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using an `xcasset` for your applications icons?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it. But error is there, so I had to do this in my `Info.plist`

Comment: Change the file name like 'Icon.png' . currently you are using file name start with small letter.

Comment: Did you rename your `png` image from `AppIcon60x60` to `icon-60`? You may just have to remove the icon and add it back it to your project. Xcode will not update the reference sometimes.

Comment: the same error did you get in xcasset? if you have set properly there no need to add all this in plist

Comment: If you're using an `xcasset` none of this is necessary. Just select the `xcasset` in your projects settings.

Comment: This link may help you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494766/where-do-i-set-the-application-icon-in-an-iphone-app

Comment: Ya I'm using `xcasset` but it's not working, I don't know why.

Comment: @Kos2008 The image in your question clearly shows that you are *not* using xcasset for your icons.

Comment: @rmaddy Yes I'm using it, but I cut image. Should I post image of xcasset ?

Comment: If you are using an asset catalog for your app's icons, there is nothing you need to add to supporting files or Info.plist.

Comment: @rmaddy Can you read comments ? I mentioned that it doesn't work there are two errors, so I had to use this in `Info.plist`.

Comment: Whats the error you receive if you remove all the `info.plist` icon stuff you've added ,remove the icon files outside of the `xcasset`, and select the `xcasset` for your app icons under your project settings?

Comment: @DanielStorm check my question again, I edited it.

Comment: I've added an answer. You're aware of what a 3x 40pt icon size should be, correct? It would be 120x120 pixels. 40 points x 3 = 120x120.

Answer (score 10):

My problem was that I generated the icons from a jpeg. I fixed the `ERROR ITMS-90032` error by converting the original jpeg to png and generating the icons again.

https://appicon.co was used for generating the icons.

Comment: Exactly my case. I'm now aware that some generators, even if you feed them with a JPEG, will output fake PNG files for iOS. Open a generated png with an hex editor to double check its true signature (if you see JFIF on the first bytes, it's a jpeg).

Comment: Thanks Vinit I've spent hours trying to debug

Answer (score 4):

Once you've removed all the `info.plist` icon stuff you've added, mainly `CFBundleIcons`, and removed the icon files outside of the `xcasset`, under your *Supporting Files* Group, select the `xcasset` for your app icons under your project's settings.

For example:
[image]

Once you've done that you need to address this issue:

> ERROR ITMS-90022: "Missing required icon file. The bundle does not contain an app icon for iPhone / iPod Touch of exactly '120x120' pixels, in .png format for iOS versions >= 7.0."

Check that the icons dimensions are exactly 120x120 and the icon is indeed in `PNG` format. You may have saved it as a `JPG`, or another file format, with a `PNG` extension.

Comment: This was my case - two icon files was jpg's saved as png's while others were real png's. Spent about 2 hours trying to clean project, figure out what is going on.

Comment: Same for me! It had an extension of PNG but someone had tried to add JPEG images and editing the contents.json file - CHECK YOUR IMAGE INFO!

Answer (score 1):

**Had the same issue.**

**Solved** by creating new Assets and creating new app icon in there and using it instead of the one in initially created assets.

How to create new assets: go to your Target > General Tab > Scroll down to "App icons..."
[image]

Then click to some random class file (so that the current screen will be closed and reloaded). Then go back to this page (where you just clicked "don't use asset catalogs"). Then you will see the button "use assets" > click it > create new assets > will create new assets > create new app icon > add icons > again in App Icons setting > choose the right app icon of new assets.

Hope this saved your time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by fixing all of the images manually.

[Xcode>*Project*>images.xcassets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGOdn.png)

this shows the corrected AppIcon section.  Many of the resolutions were either empty or incorrect before.  I did a right click>show in finder on the highest resolution icon, and duplicated it into the missing resolutions.  I then resized the png's to match the desired size.

I then changed the naming convention in the directory to match the string from the error- in my case "40x40" etc.

My next archive uploaded just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the Icon in info.plist did the job for me, added the AppIcon.appiconset again after remov