# How to fix ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'”?

Tags: ios, xcode

I've encountered `How to fix ERROR ITMS-90032: “Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons': 'AppIcon60x60'”?` error when I'm trying to submit my app to appstore. I'm using XCode 8.7.1.

Please let me know how to fix that issue. Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811393/how-to-fix-error-itms-90032-invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-re

Comment: issue not solved yet

Comment: check to make sure you've got the image names correct, and that they're in the correct format (PNG), and that the sizes are correct. you may also have an old/incorrect reference in you .plist