# Fastlane and xcode deploying to testFlight error, Invalid Image Path - No image found at the path referenced under key 'CFBundleIcons':AppIcon40x40”

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, app-store-connect, react-native-ios

it's been days I am having an issue with this stupid error and still no fix after reading tons of StackOverflow solutions. I am deploying my app to the apple connect test flight and Fastlane config is ok and goes through the process fine. it reaches the part where it wants to upload the app to our team test flight account and this error keeps popping up.

solutions tried:

- removing images and adding them again
- drag and drop images manually
- removed tvos carplay
- adding CFBundleIconName to info.plist
- looking for CFBundleIcons and adding it manually (there were no such key in my info.plist)
- adding icon names under icon files in info.plist

my icons are under `Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset`

Comment: As the error says, you are missing 40by40 size app icon. Are you sure, you have added it ?

Comment: I have. everything is in place. I used https://makeappicon.com/ and only used the iPhone but the problem is that it doesn't find my images somehow! (40x40) is one them actually it says cant find 20x20 and other sizes and at the end, it says Missing required icon file.

Comment: Have you actually opened the asset set in Xcode? You need to drag the unassigned images into the dotted rounded rectangles.

Comment: Did you confirm if all the image in the AppIcon uploaded properly without any warning in Xcode?

Comment: Yes all of the sizes are correct no complain in xcode

Comment: If you do it manually, can you upload your app to test flight ?

Comment: I don't have a device, but my college did build it and archive it, and that uploaded to test flight no problem. the problem is when we try to deploy via Fastlane

Comment: Can you post the Fastlane execution log?

Comment: @Gianluca https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36811393/how-to-fix-error-itms-90032-invalid-image-path-no-image-found-at-the-path-re
it's the same as this question with different sizes missing complain by Fastlane not much log to be honest.

Comment: Are you using the same Scheme in Xcode and TestFlight?